# $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] ajax

Tags: php, javascript

Как получить значение `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` через javascript?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

у меня есть фирма для отправки файлов. через php  я могу работать с $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. но не могу отдельно передать значение $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] на обработчик через ajax.